# Git Diff Shows Reversed Colors/Indicators

Tags: git

I am looking at my git diff and the lines are exactly reversed. New lines show with "-"s and red colors, and the removed lines show with "+"s and green colors.

```
+ deleted line [green]
- newline [red]
```

Nothing in my .gitconfig seems to indicate anything amiss.

Anyone ever seen this happen before? What did you do to fix? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please give the exact command you're running? It seems you've interchanged two arguments.

Comment: yes. thank you. stupid me. but I learned something. thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The direction of the diff is important:
`git diff A B` will provide different output than `git diff B A` and the difference will be in reversing what was deleted and what was added.

Answer (score 6):

In `git diff A B`, A is the one in red and B is the one in green (as Eugene said, the order matters)

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct the inner `diff` to consider its inputs reversed using the `-R` option:

```
git diff -R
```

But this is a kludge.  You'd better clarify what exactly you're diffing and instruct `git` to compare things in the order you actually expect.